# Canny Edge Detection: Trying to Make White Lines Only, No Black Background Over Video

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project where I am to have a camera detect the edges of objects using Canny Edge Detection. However, for the project I have to make the black background(see picture) transparent, played over the original black and white footage of the camera. How do I go about this? Note: in the dark.

[black and white shot of a calendar(left), canny(right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qGle.png)

Below is the code I used.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
   #Captures video, frame-by-frame
   _, frame = cap.read()
   frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   blurred_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5,5),0)


   canny1 = cv2.Canny(blurred_frame, 15, 20)
   #Displays the output.
   cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
   cv2.imshow("Canny1", canny1)
#Press Q to stop loop, then proceed to end program as shown below.
   key = cv2.waitKey(1)
   if key == ord('q'):
      break
#End Program
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in c,++ you would use canny1_brg.copyTo(frame, canny1 > 0) where canny1_bgr is the GRAY2BGR converted canny image and canny1>0 is the mask that you want to dosplay over your frane

Comment: You could compute the maximum value of both images.

Answer (score 0):

```
canny1 = cv2.bitwise_or(frame, canny1)
```